# Is there a way to get a MySQL table defined encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I see I can get a MySQL database defined encoding in PHP using the function `mysql_client_encoding(...)`, but **is there a way to get a MySQL table defined encoding in PHP?**

Comment: You'd better realize that this info is totally useless and can wrong you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no easy way to retrieve this info. The best I could do is to do a "SHOW CREATE TABLE ;" and parse the answer:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'account', 'passwd');
mysql_select_db('my_base');

$q = mysql_query('show create table my_table;');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

preg_match("/CHARSET=(.*)/", $row['Create Table'], $matched);
echo "Table was created with charset " . $matched[1];
```

Which gives me:

```
Table was created with charset utf8
```

Note that charset may not be present if your table was not created with this info.

Comment: Yeah but what's the use if you can create columns inside that table using a different character set or collation? You'd have to be very stupid to rely on this, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query, but never from PHP.
Because I can't imagine if I ever need to run it from PHP. `SET NAMES` can serve any possible case.

Note that mysql_client_encoding() returns not database encoding. It's client encoding, as it says

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the encoding is defined on a per database basis in MySQL and not per table.